# MCI Device shows Incorrect Media Length

Tags: vb.net, delphi, mci, mcisendstring

Sometimes the MCI device shows Incorrect Media Length for some particular media. I searched a lot in Google and the only solution I could find is written in Delphi ([Delphi Solution](http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-vb-PLEf4Z83yR/)) I couldn't find any Delphi to C# or VB converter. Is there any workaround for this problem ? I just want my Media length to be correct.

Comment: Get down to learn Delphi. Mastering it is a valuable skill.

Comment: Please clarify your question! Do you want to process mp3 files header?

Comment: @menjaraz not just mp3, I want the correct track length for every media that I can play. I am not sure if I have to process the header

Comment: The Delphi resource you pointed at deals with MP3 and based the lenght computation on header processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head to this [page](http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier_fullscreen.aspx?id=6368&f=Module1.bas) of a *french* visual basic community site.

- **mp3_header** retrieves in hex the header of the mp3 passed as parameter to it. It can serve as a good start to convert the delphi `function getmp3length(NameOfFile:string):integer` since it processes the header and expects also a file name as a parameter.

Good luck!

**Edit:**

You can also find on `The Code Project` site (in english) an interesting [VB.NET project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/vbmp3header.aspx) doing MP3 header manipulation. Hopefully It helps you in your conversion effort.

Comment: Is the header processing same for every media file ?

Comment: Please see the [About MCI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704979%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) entry on MSDN to have access to first hand information.